# Putting unordered items into an array from a file

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I have three CSV files with data that is linked by a string of numbers, I've created a 2d array to store all the data together and have one of the csv files, the data in the other files is not in the same order so I can't simply read line 1 of the file into the first row of the array.

Here's my code

```
public class grades {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    int rowc = 0;
    String inputLine = "";

    String[][] students = new String[10][6];
    //Get scanner instance
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/IRStudents.csv"));

    //Set the delimiter used in file
    scanner.useDelimiter(",");

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        inputLine = scanner.nextLine();
        String [] line = inputLine.split(",");

        for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
            students[rowc][x] = line[x];
        }
        if (rowc < 9) {
            rowc++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(students));
    scanner.close();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("/IR101.csv"));
    input.useDelimiter(",");
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        inputLine = input.nextLine();
        String[] line = inputLine.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(line[0]);
            System.out.println(students[0][i]);
            if (line[0].equals(students[0][i])) {
                students[2][i] = line[0];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(students));

}
}
```

I know a lot of it's not very tidy or efficient, but I'd rather it was working. Anyway, how would I loop through the file and add each item to the 3rd column of the array where the corresponding string is that links them?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use a csv reader and not scanner will make your code look cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understood your problem correctly.

In your case, you could load the 3rd csv into memory and then loop through the arrays (a **for** inside another **for**) and check the keys of one array that matches the key on the other (strings that links them) and bind them.

tip: you could initialize the students attributes like this:

```
students[rowc] = line;
```